# Is there any reason why you get 4 points for a win and 2 for a draw in AFL

Tags: rules, history, australian-rules-football

Is there some way you can get 1 point or 3 points for a match?

If not, it appears to be easier to do the standard 2 points for a win, 1 point for a draw, 0 for a loss. Is there some historical reason why this has been the case?

Comment: There's nothing in the rules, nothing in the regulations, and no defined penalties that apply to competition points. Almost guaranteed to be a historical thing, if something can dig it up.

Comment: There is no real reason for this, apart from there also being no real reason to change it. In some leagues (such as the SANFL), you do get 2 points for a win and 1 point for a draw.